# Copy video from USB device to desktop in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, unix, file-transfer, shell-script

I'd like to set up a script that performs the following tasks

1. Starts a count down timer or delay
2. On completion of timer checks remote USB device (a camera) for the
   presence of a video file
3. If this file exists, starts to copy this file to local desktop
4. Upon completion of copy, deletes this video file on the USB device

What would be the series of shell commands or methods I need to research to accomplish the above? Is there any reason why OSX is not an ideal platform for this?

Comment: Does the file have a predictable name to check if it's there?

Comment: Yes, the name will be consistent

Comment: Does it need to do anything special if the file isn't there?

Comment: if the video is not present will display some sort of error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question a second time, it seems like you just want us to point you in the direction of some relevant commands.

#### Possibly relevant commands/bash features:

- `sleep` delays for the number of seconds specified
- `[ -f /path/to/file ]` checks if there is a file at the specified path
- `cp` copy a file from one place to another
- `rm` delete a file

For more information on any of those see `man <command>` for more information on the `[ -f ]` one see `man test`.

#### Example script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sleep $1 # This will sleep for whatever number is put in when calling this script.
if [ -f ~/from/video ]; then
        if cp ~/from/video ~/to && rm ~/from/video; then
                echo "Transfer successful."
        else
                echo "Failed to copy."
        fi
else
        echo "There is no video at location '~/from/video'."
fi
```

#### Usage

```
$ ./script 2
```

(Blinks for two seconds)

```
Transfer successful.
```

Comment: Edited to relfect edit to question

Comment: @eco_bach Glad to know I could help!

Comment: @eco_bach Also, just a warning, the `~` in `~/from/video` means my home directory, so if your video was on a drive you had have to do something like `/MyDrive/video` (has no `~`).